Question for Proving Cancellation of Infrared Divergence for All Order of Perturbation Theory in Peskin&Schroeder QFT and Weinberg's Paper
In Peskin&Schroeder QFT and also Weinberg's paper, they shows the cancellation of infrared divergence to all order of perturbation theory.
Weinberg shows that only when the soft photon with momentum $q$ is attached to the external line will the S-matrix element has pole like $1/p\cdot q$, where $p$ is the momentum of external line.
Then, in equation (6.78) of P&S and (2.11) of Weinberg's paper, they connect two external soft photon lines to form a loop, or a virtual photon.
$$S_{\beta\alpha} = S_{\beta\alpha}^{0}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\int^{\Delta}_{\Lambda}d^4q\,A(q)\right)\tag{2.11}$$
My question is, in the following computation, they extract the infra-red part out of whole S-matrix element $S_{\beta\alpha}$, but as far as I'm concerned, the S-matrix element $S_{\beta\alpha}^0$ without infra-red virtual photon should depend on photon momentum $q$ too!
Why can Weinberg write the S-matrix element $S_{\beta\alpha}^0$ out of the integration?
